# how to wait for the response from paypal after the payment is successful?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, paypal, paypal-ipn

I would like to integrate a payment system but I don't see how I should wait for the response from paypal once the person has paid. all the examples on the internet are based on asp.net, I don't think we can do the same thing........................................................................................................................

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PayPalCheckoutSdk.Core;
using PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders;
using PayPalCheckoutSdk.Payments;
using PayPalHttp;

namespace Discord.Modules
{
    public class PaypalPayment
    {
        private static OrderRequest BuildRequestBody()
        {
            OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest()
            {
                CheckoutPaymentIntent = "CAPTURE",

                ApplicationContext = new ApplicationContext
                {
                    BrandName = "EXAMPLE INC",
                    LandingPage = "BILLING",
                    CancelUrl = "https://www.example.com",
                    ReturnUrl = "https://www.example.com",
                    UserAction = "CONTINUE",
                    ShippingPreference = "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS"
                },
                PurchaseUnits = new List<PurchaseUnitRequest>
                {
                    new PurchaseUnitRequest{
                        ReferenceId =  "PUHF",
                        Description = "Sporting Goods",
                        CustomId = "CUST-HighFashions",
                        SoftDescriptor = "HighFashions",
                        AmountWithBreakdown = new AmountWithBreakdown
                        {
                            CurrencyCode = "USD",
                            Value = "220.00",
                            AmountBreakdown = new AmountBreakdown
                            {
                                ItemTotal = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                    Value = "180.00"
                                },
                                Shipping = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                    Value = "20.00"
                                },
                                Handling = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                    Value = "10.00"
                                },
                                TaxTotal = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                    Value = "20.00"
                                },
                                ShippingDiscount = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                    Value = "10.00"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        Items = new List<Item>
                        {
                            new Item
                            {
                                Name = "T-shirt",
                                Description = "Green XL",
                                Sku = "sku01",
                                UnitAmount = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                    Value = "90.00"
                                },
                                Tax = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                    Value = "10.00"
                                },
                                Quantity = "1",
                                Category = "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                            },
                            new Item
                            {
                                Name = "Shoes",
                                Description = "Running, Size 10.5",
                                Sku = "sku02",
                                UnitAmount = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                    Value = "45.00"
                                },
                                Tax = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                                {
                                    CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                    Value = "5.00"
                                },
                                Quantity = "2",
                                Category = "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                            }
                        },
                        ShippingDetail = new ShippingDetail
                        {
                            Name = new Name
                            {
                                FullName = "John Doe"
                            },
                            AddressPortable = new AddressPortable
                            {
                                AddressLine1 = "123 Townsend St",
                                AddressLine2 = "Floor 6",
                                AdminArea2 = "San Francisco",
                                AdminArea1 = "CA",
                                PostalCode = "94107",
                                CountryCode = "US"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            return orderRequest;
        }


        public async static Task<HttpResponse> CreateOrder(bool debug = false)
        {
            var request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
            request.Headers.Add("prefer", "return=representation");
            request.RequestBody(BuildRequestBody());
            var client = PayPalClient.client();
            var response = await client.Execute(request);

            if (debug)
            {
                var result = response.Result<Order>();
                Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", result.Status);
                Console.WriteLine("Order Id: {0}", result.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Intent: {0}", result.CheckoutPaymentIntent);
                Console.WriteLine("Links:");
                foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.LinkDescription link in result.Links)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}\tCall Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method);
                }
                AmountWithBreakdown amount = result.PurchaseUnits[0].AmountWithBreakdown;
                Console.WriteLine("Total Amount: {0} {1}", amount.CurrencyCode, amount.Value);
                Console.WriteLine("Response JSON: \n {0}", PayPalClient.ObjectToJSONString(result));
            }

            return response;
        }

        public async static Task<HttpResponse> CaptureOrder(string OrderId, bool debug = false)
        {
            var request = new OrdersCaptureRequest(OrderId);
            request.Prefer("return=representation");
            request.RequestBody(new OrderActionRequest());
            var client = PayPalClient.client();
            var response = await client.Execute(request);

            if (debug)
            {
                var result = response.Result<Order>();
                Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", result.Status);
                Console.WriteLine("Order Id: {0}", result.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Intent: {0}", result.CheckoutPaymentIntent);
                Console.WriteLine("Links:");
                foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.LinkDescription link in result.Links)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}\tCall Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Capture Ids: ");
                foreach (PurchaseUnit purchaseUnit in result.PurchaseUnits)
                {
                    foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Capture capture in purchaseUnit.Payments.Captures)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t {0}", capture.Id);
                    }
                }
                AmountWithBreakdown amount = result.PurchaseUnits[0].AmountWithBreakdown;
                Console.WriteLine("Buyer:");
                Console.WriteLine("\tEmail Address: {0}\n\tName: {1} {2}\n",
                    result.Payer.Email,
                    result.Payer.Name.GivenName,
                    result.Payer.Name.Surname);
                Console.WriteLine("Response JSON:\n{0}", PayPalClient.ObjectToJSONString(result));
            }

            return response;
        }


        public static async Task asdasd()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running Capture Intent Flow..");
            var createOrderResponse = CreateOrder(true).Result;
            var createOrderResult = createOrderResponse.Result<Order>();
            Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", createOrderResult.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("Order Id: {0}", createOrderResult.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Intent: {0}", createOrderResult.CheckoutPaymentIntent);
            Console.WriteLine("Links:");
            foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.LinkDescription link in createOrderResult.Links)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}\tCall Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method);
            }
            AmountWithBreakdown amount = createOrderResult.PurchaseUnits[0].AmountWithBreakdown;
            Console.WriteLine("Total Amount: {0} {1}", amount.CurrencyCode, amount.Value);

            Console.WriteLine("Copy approve link and paste it in browser. Login with buyer account and follow the instructions.\nOnce approved hit enter...\n");
            Console.Read();

            Console.WriteLine("Capturing the payment...");
            var captureOrderResponse = CaptureOrder(createOrderResult.Id, true).Result;
            var captureOrderResult = captureOrderResponse.Result<Order>();
            var captureId = "";
            Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", captureOrderResult.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("Order Id: {0}", captureOrderResult.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Intent: {0}", captureOrderResult.CheckoutPaymentIntent);
            Console.WriteLine("Links:");
            foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.LinkDescription link in captureOrderResult.Links)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}\tCall Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method);
            }
            foreach (PurchaseUnit purchaseUnit in captureOrderResult.PurchaseUnits)
            {
                foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Capture capture in purchaseUnit.Payments.Captures)
                {
                    captureId = capture.Id;
                }
            }
            AmountWithBreakdown captureAmount = captureOrderResult.PurchaseUnits[0].AmountWithBreakdown;
            Console.WriteLine("Buyer:");
            Console.WriteLine("\tEmail Address: {0}\n\tName: {1} {2}",
            captureOrderResult.Payer.Email, captureOrderResult.Payer.Name.GivenName, captureOrderResult.Payer.Name.Surname);

            Console.WriteLine("Refunding the Order....");
            var refundOrderResponse = CapturesRefund(captureId, true).Result;
            var refundOrderResult = refundOrderResponse.Result<PayPalCheckoutSdk.Payments.Refund>();
            Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", refundOrderResult.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("Refund Id: {0}", refundOrderResult.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Links:");
            foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Payments.LinkDescription link in refundOrderResult.Links)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}\tCall Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method);
            }
        }

        public async static Task<HttpResponse> CapturesRefund(string CaptureId, bool debug = false)
        {
            var request = new CapturesRefundRequest(CaptureId);
            request.Prefer("return=representation");
            RefundRequest refundRequest = new RefundRequest()
            {
                Amount = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Payments.Money
                {
                    Value = "20.00",
                    CurrencyCode = "USD"
                }
            };
            request.RequestBody(refundRequest);
            var response = await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request);

            if (debug)
            {
                var result = response.Result<PayPalCheckoutSdk.Payments.Refund>();
                Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", result.Status);
                Console.WriteLine("Refund Id: {0}", result.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("Links:");
                foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Payments.LinkDescription link in result.Links)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}\tCall Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Response JSON: \n {0}", PayPalClient.ObjectToJSONString(result));
            }
            return response;
        }

    }

    public class PayPalClient
    {
        /**
            Setting up PayPal environment with credentials with sandbox cerdentails. 
            For Live, this should be LiveEnvironment Instance. 
         */
        public static PayPalEnvironment environment()
        {
            return new SandboxEnvironment(
                 System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("") != null ?
                 System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("") : "",
                System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("") != null ?
                 System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("") : "");
        }

        /**
            Returns PayPalHttpClient instance which can be used to invoke PayPal API's.
         */
        public static HttpClient client()
        {
            return new PayPalHttpClient(environment());
        }

        public static HttpClient client(string refreshToken)
        {
            return new PayPalHttpClient(environment(), refreshToken);
        }

        /**
            This method can be used to Serialize Object to JSON string.
        */
        public static String ObjectToJSONString(Object serializableObject)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(
                        memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, true, "  ");
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(serializableObject.GetType(), new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true });
            ser.WriteObject(writer, serializableObject);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not clear how are you integrating with paypal. Kindly share the relevant code and explain the problem you are facing.

Comment: well I'm trying to find a way to run the code after the person has paid how to do it in a console app?

Comment: asp.net you can use httppost and many other little things that will execute code after payment but I don't see how to do it with a console app

Comment: how are you asking person to pay? where user go to do the payment? is your application integrated with paypal? are you calling any method or URL of paypal from the console application?

Comment: no I give him the link and then he pays

Comment: what link do you give him? the link to paypal or the link to another page on your website?

Comment: The way I've done this in the past has been to make a http post call to your paypal provider and based on their response, you decide what to do next

Comment: What's the real problem you are trying to solve by having payment done via console application?

Comment: My project is to create a PayPal link for the customer, that link sends them a invoice and then when the client paid I get a confirmation message

Comment: the real problem is that I don't know what to do to wait for the response from paypal

Comment: the real problem is that I don't know what to do to wait for the response from paypal !!!!!!!!!

Comment: You share a link with the user.. User may or may not do the payment immediately. Console application do not have a way to check if the payment is completed.... also this way console application can not serve more than one user at a time. You might need to think this from a different angle. the common way should be paypal should notify you by posting data to your URL and then you take action when you get data... but notification to console app is not possible. Why you must use console application? are you creating a POC or sample code?

Comment: there is no other way to send a link and wait for a payment?
if I make a console app it's because I'm making a discord bot

Comment: May be you can run a background check, in loop, against the paypal by calling paypal api to check if the payment is completed.... and when you get success response from paypal you can take next step else keep checking until the timeout (let say, give 15 min to the user to complete the payment). If user does not complete the payment in 15 mins you can expire the payment link.

Comment: yes I thought about it but there are 2 problems if there are two people who want to pay what do I do? I said to myself that there should be a way to put information in the payment that allows me to know the user, is it possible?

Comment: there is also a problem is that if I have no answer the execution of the code will end there I do not know how to avoid this

Comment: var response = await client.Execute(request);
it does not crash but it does nothing after its

Comment: can you share your relevant code in the question? you have more than one issues to solve and they can't be solved based on the information you provided... it is not clear how are you generating the link, do you generate the link by calling paypal api? is there a way to identify each payment uniquely? does paypal provides api to check the payment status? does the payment link have expiry? how much well verse you are in creating discord bot which works with multiple users (I am not a bot developer)?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static OrderRequest BuildRequestBody()
    {
        OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest()
        {
            CheckoutPaymentIntent = "CAPTURE",

            ApplicationContext = new ApplicationContext
            {
                BrandName = "EXAMPLE INC",
                LandingPage = "BILLING",
                CancelUrl = "https://www.example.com",
                ReturnUrl = "https://www.example.com",
                UserAction = "CONTINUE",
                ShippingPreference = "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS"
            },
            PurchaseUnits = new List<PurchaseUnitRequest>
            {
                new PurchaseUnitRequest{
                    ReferenceId =  "PUHF",
                    Description = "Sporting Goods",
                    CustomId = "CUST-HighFashions",
                    SoftDescriptor = "HighFashions",
                    AmountWithBreakdown = new AmountWithBreakdown
                    {
                        CurrencyCode = "USD",
                        Value = "220.00",
                        AmountBreakdown = new AmountBreakdown
                        {
                            ItemTotal = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                            {
                                CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                Value = "180.00"
                            },
                            Shipping = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                            {
                                CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                Value = "20.00"
                            },
                            Handling = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                            {
                                CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                Value = "10.00"
                            },
                            TaxTotal = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                            {
                                CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                Value = "20.00"
                            },
                            ShippingDiscount = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                            {
                                CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                Value = "10.00"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    Items = new List<Item>
                    {
                        new Item
                        {
                            Name = "T-shirt",
                            Description = "Green XL",
                            Sku = "sku01",
                            UnitAmount = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                            {
                                CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                Value = "90.00"
                            },
                            Tax = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                            {
                                CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                Value = "10.00"
                            },
                            Quantity = "1",
                            Category = "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                        },
                        new Item
                        {
                            Name = "Shoes",
                            Description = "Running, Size 10.5",
                            Sku = "sku02",
                            UnitAmount = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                            {
                                CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                Value = "45.00"
                            },
                            Tax = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Money
                            {
                                CurrencyCode = "USD",
                                Value = "5.00"
                            },
                            Quantity = "2",
                            Category = "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                        }
                    },
                    ShippingDetail = new ShippingDetail
                    {
                        Name = new Name
                        {
                            FullName = "John Doe"
                        },
                        AddressPortable = new AddressPortable
                        {
                            AddressLine1 = "123 Townsend St",
                            AddressLine2 = "Floor 6",
                            AdminArea2 = "San Francisco",
                            AdminArea1 = "CA",
                            PostalCode = "94107",
                            CountryCode = "US"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        return orderRequest;
    }


    public async static Task<HttpResponse> CreateOrder(bool debug = false)
    {
        var request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
        request.Headers.Add("prefer", "return=representation");
        request.RequestBody(BuildRequestBody());
        var client = PayPalClient.client();
        var response = await client.Execute(request);

        if (debug)
        {
            var result = response.Result<Order>();
            Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", result.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("Order Id: {0}", result.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Intent: {0}", result.CheckoutPaymentIntent);
            Console.WriteLine("Links:");
            foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.LinkDescription link in result.Links)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}\tCall Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method);
            }
            AmountWithBreakdown amount = result.PurchaseUnits[0].AmountWithBreakdown;
            Console.WriteLine("Total Amount: {0} {1}", amount.CurrencyCode, amount.Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Response JSON: \n {0}", PayPalClient.ObjectToJSONString(result));
        }

        return response;
    }

    public async static Task<HttpResponse> CaptureOrder(string OrderId, bool debug = false)
    {
        var request = new OrdersCaptureRequest(OrderId);
        request.Prefer("return=representation");
        request.RequestBody(new OrderActionRequest());
        var client = PayPalClient.client();
        var response = await client.Execute(request);

        if (debug)
        {
            var result = response.Result<Order>();
            Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", result.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("Order Id: {0}", result.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Intent: {0}", result.CheckoutPaymentIntent);
            Console.WriteLine("Links:");
            foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.LinkDescription link in result.Links)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}\tCall Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Capture Ids: ");
            foreach (PurchaseUnit purchaseUnit in result.PurchaseUnits)
            {
                foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Capture capture in purchaseUnit.Payments.Captures)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t {0}", capture.Id);
                }
            }
            AmountWithBreakdown amount = result.PurchaseUnits[0].AmountWithBreakdown;
            Console.WriteLine("Buyer:");
            Console.WriteLine("\tEmail Address: {0}\n\tName: {1} {2}\n",
                result.Payer.Email,
                result.Payer.Name.GivenName,
                result.Payer.Name.Surname);
            Console.WriteLine("Response JSON:\n{0}", PayPalClient.ObjectToJSONString(result));
        }

        return response;
    }


    public static async Task asdasd()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running Capture Intent Flow..");
        var createOrderResponse = CreateOrder(true).Result;
        var createOrderResult = createOrderResponse.Result<Order>();
        Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", createOrderResult.Status);
        Console.WriteLine("Order Id: {0}", createOrderResult.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Intent: {0}", createOrderResult.CheckoutPaymentIntent);
        Console.WriteLine("Links:");
        foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.LinkDescription link in createOrderResult.Links)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}\tCall Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method);
        }
        AmountWithBreakdown amount = createOrderResult.PurchaseUnits[0].AmountWithBreakdown;
        Console.WriteLine("Total Amount: {0} {1}", amount.CurrencyCode, amount.Value);

        Console.WriteLine("Copy approve link and paste it in browser. Login with buyer account and follow the instructions.\nOnce approved hit enter...\n");
        Console.Read();

        Console.WriteLine("Capturing the payment...");
        var captureOrderResponse = CaptureOrder(createOrderResult.Id, true).Result;
        var captureOrderResult = captureOrderResponse.Result<Order>();
        var captureId = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", captureOrderResult.Status);
        Console.WriteLine("Order Id: {0}", captureOrderResult.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Intent: {0}", captureOrderResult.CheckoutPaymentIntent);
        Console.WriteLine("Links:");
        foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.LinkDescription link in captureOrderResult.Links)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}\tCall Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method);
        }
        foreach (PurchaseUnit purchaseUnit in captureOrderResult.PurchaseUnits)
        {
            foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.Capture capture in purchaseUnit.Payments.Captures)
            {
                captureId = capture.Id;
            }
        }
        AmountWithBreakdown captureAmount = captureOrderResult.PurchaseUnits[0].AmountWithBreakdown;
        Console.WriteLine("Buyer:");
        Console.WriteLine("\tEmail Address: {0}\n\tName: {1} {2}",
        captureOrderResult.Payer.Email, captureOrderResult.Payer.Name.GivenName, captureOrderResult.Payer.Name.Surname);

        Console.WriteLine("Refunding the Order....");
        var refundOrderResponse = CapturesRefund(captureId, true).Result;
        var refundOrderResult = refundOrderResponse.Result<PayPalCheckoutSdk.Payments.Refund>();
        Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", refundOrderResult.Status);
        Console.WriteLine("Refund Id: {0}", refundOrderResult.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Links:");
        foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Payments.LinkDescription link in refundOrderResult.Links)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}\tCall Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method);
        }
    }

    public async static Task<HttpResponse> CapturesRefund(string CaptureId, bool debug = false)
    {
        var request = new CapturesRefundRequest(CaptureId);
        request.Prefer("return=representation");
        RefundRequest refundRequest = new RefundRequest()
        {
            Amount = new PayPalCheckoutSdk.Payments.Money
            {
                Value = "20.00",
                CurrencyCode = "USD"
            }
        };
        request.RequestBody(refundRequest);
        var response = await PayPalClient.client().Execute(request);

        if (debug)
        {
            var result = response.Result<PayPalCheckoutSdk.Payments.Refund>();
            Console.WriteLine("Status: {0}", result.Status);
            Console.WriteLine("Refund Id: {0}", result.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Links:");
            foreach (PayPalCheckoutSdk.Payments.LinkDescription link in result.Links)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}: {1}\tCall Type: {2}", link.Rel, link.Href, link.Method);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Response JSON: \n {0}", PayPalClient.ObjectToJSONString(result));
        }
        return response;
    }

}

public class PayPalClient
{
    /**
        Setting up PayPal environment with credentials with sandbox cerdentails. 
        For Live, this should be LiveEnvironment Instance. 
     */
    public static PayPalEnvironment environment()
    {
        return new SandboxEnvironment(
             System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("") != null ?
             System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("") : "",
            System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("") != null ?
             System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("") : "");
    }

    /**
        Returns PayPalHttpClient instance which can be used to invoke PayPal API's.
     */
    public static HttpClient client()
    {
        return new PayPalHttpClient(environment());
    }

    public static HttpClient client(string refreshToken)
    {
        return new PayPalHttpClient(environment(), refreshToken);
    }

    /**
        This method can be used to Serialize Object to JSON string.
    */
    public static String ObjectToJSONString(Object serializableObject)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(
                    memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, true, true, "  ");
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(serializableObject.GetType(), new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true });
        ser.WriteObject(writer, serializableObject);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to add this code to the oiginal question by editing it, not post it as answer.

Comment: sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Your code is already using the Checkout-NET-SDK (that abstracts the v2/checkout/orders PayPal REST API) to create and capture a PayPal order. The capture API response provides an immediate notification of success or failure. In particular `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id` is the PayPal transaction ID and what should be persisted in your database. The order total should also be validated at this point in time.

---

Separately, it appears you are using an old redirect-based flow for the approval. Instead, follow the [PayPal Checkout integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/) guide and have the create order and capture order API steps be performed by 2 routes (url paths) on your server.  Both of these routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The 2nd route takes an order id as an input parameter (path or body variable) and as mentioned should examine the result of the operation to verify the amount was correct and store its resulting payment details, as well as performing any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) immediately *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend caller. In the event of an error forward the JSON details of it as well, since the frontend must handle such cases.

Pair those 2 routes with this frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server .  (If you need to send any additional data from the client to the server, such as an items array or selected options, add a `body` parameter to the fetch with a value that is a JSON string or object)

Comment: Hi you just told me what I should do if I was in asp.net but I'm doing it on a console application

Comment: The approval must happen in a web browser, so if you are not implementing a website with the JS SDK then you must open a browser to the approval link somehow, and have a place for the browser to return to, specified in the return_url.  The return_url must be a valid place the browser can go to after the PayPal payment is made, and it must trigger the capture API. It is not optional.